# Doubts about reading files

Tags: python, io

I have a Python file with this struct:

A string I want to extract plus some other information, like integers

For example: `**Room** 61201 1 png`

There are a bunch of lines following the model. And to extract what I would like, I thought in ask for Python read the characters WHILE the character is different of SPACE. When character is space, go to next line and continue doing it.

However, I don't know how to implement that... could you guys help me?

[UPDATED]
I would like to store each information (Room, car, fan...) in a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read through a file line by line (and execute some action for every line) like this:

```
with open('filename') as file:
    for line in file:
        #do something with line here
```

Then use `string.split()` to form an array, adding a new item whenever it reads a space. So:

```
array = []
with open('filename') as file:
    for line in file:
        array.append(line.split())

#Result: [['**Room**', '61201', '1', 'png']]
```

And you can manipulate the info in the array however you'd like.

In order to access specific information from line in your new array, run a simple for loop like so:

```
item1 = []
item2 = []
item3 = []
item4 = []

for dataset in array:
    item1.append(dataset[0])
    item2.append(dataset[1])
    item3.append(dataset[2])
    item4.append(dataset[3])
```

The more pythonic way would be to use a dictionary of arrays like this:

```
dataDict = {0: [], 1: [], 2: [], 3: []}

for dataset in array:
    for i in range(len(dataset)):
        dataDict[i].append(dataset[i])
```

As long as the data is in the same order, this will append every nth element to its own array.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I *think* the data's in a file, because (s)he wants to read it line by line ("When character is space, go to next line and continue doing it."). Also the question is called "Doubts about reading files"

Comment: Ah okay.  I'll add to my answer so at least it doesn't look stupid :P but I will upvote yours. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing, but I think https://docs.python.org/3/ would be useful for you.

To read a file, you can use `open("filename", "r")`. For each line in the file, you could use the `.split(" ")` method to make a list. Ultimately, it would look something like this:

```
data = []
file = open("filename", "r")
for line in file:
    data.append(line.split(" "))
print(data)
f.close()
```

The variable data would a be a list of lists.